# Fried potatoes absorbing oil

Tags: heat, food-chemistry

Suppose we bring a pan and put in it some oil and turn on the heat, before the oil could get very hot and nearly boiling, we put on the potatoes that start frying.

Someone told me that if the potatoes were put in oil before it gets really hot, then they will absorb more oil than if they were put in oil after it gets really hot.

Is this true?? If yes then WHY?

Note:(given that in both cases they stay the same period of time immersed in oil).

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? It will help the answerers to answer your question!

Answer (score 3):

It is an example of the [Leidenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect). Ideally the water being expelled from the food would actually keep the oil from contacting the food itself by forming a barrier of steam (vaporizing water) around the food.

Answer (score 0):

Try it first by weighing out similarly shaped potatoes before and after frying using the two methods described in order to calculate the amount on oil absorbed from the difference (do this multiple times and obtain a standard deviation so you can make sure that the difference is not due to experimental errors) and after the real answer is obtained one can start thinking why (or actually have your friend do it so he can prove you that he is correct).

My prediction is that is will make no difference on the basis that oil and water don't mix and considering that potatoes contain significant amount of water they wont let much oil in before the temperature increases (which will evaporate the water and allow the oil to move in the potato). In both cases you ll end up with potatoes saturated in fried oil.

Comment: Thank you, but potatoes don't contain only water, but other components as well, so maybe oil would be absorbed by those other components. And maybe as well to water but for a short time, because I realize that after serving the fried potatoes, after some time, the potatoes tend to leak some oil..

Comment: Potatoes are 80%  wt water. Try the experiment above and i think you ll see no difference.